# Break connections in excel while keeping values in cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have an excel workbook which has 5 worksheets. The back 4 worksheets are filled from queries in Access with values for a summary. The front worksheet is formated all nicely and has graphs and such. The values in the tables on the front sheet are pulled from the back sheets by setting the cell formulas to something like this:

```
= BackSheet1!A1
```

This works great but now I need to keep the values in the cell and break the connection so I can delete the back 4 worksheets (because thats what the boss wants).

So my question is about the execution of this. My initial idea is to create a button and put some vba behind it that pulls the values and puts them into a sixth sheet, then deletes the old 5 sheets. Is there a better way? Can I call an excel chunk of VBA from Access VBA so this happens upon creation of the file? Any other thoughts or tips are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably the simplest thing to do is highlight the cells, copy them, and do a "paste special" - just paste the values.  That way you will have results and no formulas.

Comment: Do you need to build in a functionality so your boss can do this over and over or do you just need the values. If the latter, do what @durbnpoisn suggested.

Comment: Over and over, I knew about the paste values but I would like it to be more user friendly incase someone who doesnt know the process has to do it.

Comment: In that case just write a macro to copy the sheet and paste special. And put a button on the sheet to do so. If you're not sure how that's done, simply begin `Record Macro`, press `Ctrl-A` on that sheet and do a Paste-Special and have a look at the VBE for the code.

Comment: That did it, copied and pasted. the only problem is the apllication flickers from page to page as it goes but that is not that big of a deal. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and used the record macro feature in excel, the copy and paste values behind a button in the macro, then coded in deletion of my other pages.

```
'delete other sheets
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each ws In Sheets
        If ws.Name <> "Summary" Then ws.Delete
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

So I got out of this rut in about 20 minutes with only typing 5 lines of code.